# KeyChar is not a member of System.EventArgs error

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub txtFileName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFileName.TextChanged
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
      Dim FileNameTyped As New FileInfo(Me.txtFileName.Text)
      If FileNameTyped.Exists Then
        Call ShowFileContents(Me.txtFileName.Text)
      Else
        MessageBox.Show(" File does not exist ")
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Sorry for all the code but I'm lost can you please tell me why I have an error on the "e.KeyChar"?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: "If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then"

Comment: In that sentece the e.KeyChar has an error

Comment: because `KeyChar` is not an argument to the TextChanged event

Comment: TextChanged doesn't have a KeyChar property in the EventArgs.  Were you looking for the KeyPress event?

Comment: Error 1 'KeyChar' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'. H:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReadFile\ReadFile\Form1.vb 4 12 ReadFile

Comment: Yes I guess, I want that\

Comment: Exactly. `KeyChar` is not a member of `System.EventArgs`. You're using the wrong event to detect keystrokes, as @Plutonix said already.

Comment: I need it to work when I hit enter

Comment: what event should I use. Thanks again everyone I just started learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the KeyDown event:

```
Private Sub txtFileName_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) _
                                Handles txtFileName.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    ' // do stuff
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have the exact same thing you put except i still have the same error for e.KeyCode

Comment: @AidanMcGinn you have it in THE WRONG EVENT. that makes it VERY different

Comment: @Plutonix  Ohhhhhh Im Really sorry, long night haha I got it you guys helped A Lot thanks a million!